# How do I stop adware and websites opening a new tab when I click on a link when using Chrome?

Tags: malware

I just downloaded Google Chrome and and apparently I have acquired a virus or adware, or malware because when I click on a link a website advertisement opens up a new tab. This is one of the URLs that have been been popping up: 
https://identityarmor.co/scan/revenuewire?__rwsid=tfc0g0oflkn6o5fg82fmnfq0u4. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Does it happen on a specific link or website, or all links and all websites?

Comment: adware is most likely. and those are from add-ons or extensions. you probably installed one and clicked the option (or it was active) to install this adware. remove the extension and the adware will get removed too. It wont be a virus.

Answer (score 3):

Remove any suspicious addons, extras, apps, etc. in Google Chrome.

If you just installed it then chances are it simply synced everything you got from when using Chrome in Windows, including malware.

Answer (score 3):

50 million people and myself are using `Adblock Plus` for Google Chrome. It works with Linux and Windows Chrome.

It will not only block the malware that is plaguing you now but also normal pop-up ads that appear on many websites you visit.

Near the top right of you chrome screen you will see three vertical dots. When you hover your mouse over it the caption `Customize and control Google Chrome` appears.

Click the three vertical dots and a menu appears. Select `Settings` from the mneu.

On the left side of the Settings menu there is an option called `Extensions`. Click this option.

The Extensions screen shows all the chrome extensions installed. Scan through the list for any suspicious ones and disable or delete them.

Scroll down to the bottom of the Extensions list and you'll see the option `Get more extensions`. Click this option and you'll be taken to the Chrome web store. Type `adblock plus` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The first three options displayed are `Apps`. We don't want them so scroll down and the next section titled `Extensions` is what we want. `Adblock Plus` appears first as the screenshot below illustrates:

[Adblock Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlrUy.png)

On my screen it shows as already installed but for your screen you would select `+ Add to Chrome`.

`Adblock Plus` is now installed as an Extension.

Should this answer require further explanation post a comment under it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try addblocker. Usually behind ads there's malware. Just add this addon, and you'll be all right. I tried it myself and works pretty neat.
And as mentioned earlier, remove all the suspicious addons from your browser.

Cheers!

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you would explain how so that those less tech savvy than you can obtain the benefit of your experience. Thank you!